# How to upload an image to Azure storage through PHP?

Tags: php, azure, blob, storage

I'm trying to upload an image to my blob storage via my API built with PHP.

Currently I have this, the base64 string is being sent via JSON Post.

```
//The base 64 string
$displayPictureBase64 = $this->ValidateParameter('DisplayPicture', $this->param, STRING);
//Decode it to byte array.
$displayPicture[] = base64_decode($displayPictureBase64);
//Name of the blob
$blobName = "MyBlobName";

//New BlobStorage class.
$blob = new BlobStorage;
$blob->AddBlob('user-display-pictures', $blobName, $displayPicture);
```

This calls the function AddBlob...

```
public function AddBlob($containerName, $fileName, $fileToUpload)
{
//Upload blob
$this->blobClient->createBlockBlob($containerName, $fileName, $fileToUpload);
}
```

(PS. I have the credentials for the blobClient, just didn't include it here to save unnecessary space.)

Problem I'm getting is that the function blobClient->createBlockBlob takes these parameters...

> ```
>  * @param string                          $container The name of the container.
>  * @param string                          $blob      The name of the blob.
>  * @param string|resource|StreamInterface $content   The content of the blob.
> ```

So the issue I'm having is that the 3rd parameter I am sending is of type array, but it should be string according to this.
This is the PHP error I get...

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Invalid resource type: array in D:\home\vendor\guzzlehttp\psr7\src\functions.php:116

How would I upload the image to blob storage as a string? The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-php?tabs=windows) on this only show how to upload text files, not image files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing the following...

```
//The base 64 string
$displayPictureBase64 = $this->ValidateParameter('DisplayPicture', $this->param, STRING);

//Convert the file to stream
$fileToUpload = fopen('data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $displayPictureBase64,'r');
//Name of the blob
$blobName = "MyBlobName";

//New BlobStorage class.
$blob = new BlobStorage;
$blob->AddBlob('user-display-pictures', $blobName, $fileToUpload);
```